# Cordova iOS Webview preload sound?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Very simple code here that is not working on iOS UIWebview via Cordova while perfectly working on Android , looking for a workaround. The sound is never loaded on iOS (oncanplaythrough never fired).

```
 var snd = new Audio();
 snd.preload = 'auto'; 
 snd.oncanplaythrough = function(){
      console.log('the sound is loaded!');
 });
 snd.src = 'whatever.mp3';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gonna answer my own question, it might help someone. Turns out, iOS Webview ignores

```
 snd.preload='auto';
```

but it works by removing it and doing instead

```
 snd.load();
```